# GitLab CI Runner Windows executes Powershell command differently to local Powershell

Tags: powershell, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ci.yml

I have a Powershell command that starts a program with some arguments and waits for the execution to end.
If I execute that command manually in Powershell everything works as expected.
If I execute the same command through a GitLab Runner on the same machine, the process is never actually started and the CI job succeeds immediately.

The shell command:

```
Start-Process -Passthru -FilePath "C:\Program Files\CODESYS 3.5.17.30\CODESYS\Common\CODESYS.exe" -ArgumentList "--runscript='codesys_automation.py' --profile='CODESYS V3.5 SP17 Patch 3' --noUI" | Wait-Process
```

The gitlab-ci.yml job (executed by a runner with access to the codesys.exe):

```
configure-plc:
  tags:
    - codesys
  stage: configure-plc
  script:
    - Start-Process -Passthru -FilePath "C:\Program Files\CODESYS 3.5.17.30\CODESYS\Common\CODESYS.exe" -ArgumentList "--runscript='codesys_automation.py' --profile='CODESYS V3.5 SP17 Patch 3' --noUI" | Wait-Process
```

How do I make the runner behave just like the manual Poweshell and let it print out the programms stdout output?

Comment: I don't think the codesys tag is relevant here

Comment: It's necessary so that this job is only executed by the runner on a Windows machine with Codesys installed

Comment: Guiorgy is talking about the tag for the question here on Stack Overflow and not about the tag in your Gitlab CI YAML description.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
configure-plc:
  tags:
    - codesys
  stage: configure-plc
  script:
    - '& "C:\Program Files\CODESYS 3.5.17.30\CODESYS\Common\CODESYS.exe" --runscript=codesys_automation.py --profile=CODESYS V3.5 SP17 Patch 3 --noUI'
```

Comment: can you confirm if this works? I have the same issue and this doenst work for me. - '& "C:\Keil_v5\UV4\UV4.exe" -b ePIL.uvprojx -j0 -o build'.  I tried this